# IDA "unk_XXXXXX" meaning?

Tags: ida

I am new to reverse engineering.
Today when looking at IDA, I found this

```
if ( *(_UNKNOWN **)(this + 8) == &unk_4EDC58 )
```

but I dont understand the part "unk_4EDC58".

So can you help me ? Thank you !

Comment: @Biswapriyo oh sorry, my bad.... Do I need to delete this question ? This is the second time I ask a question on SO

Comment: No, no, don't delete your question. This is a valid Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IDA, it means this part of memory, at the address 0x004EDC58, doesn't have any types.

It's hard to be 100% sure with only one line of decompiled code, but I guess this code is typical from cl.exe (Microsoft C++ compiler) when it tries to inline a virtual method. To do so, it will directly check if the method (this + 8) is equal to the current method (0x004EDC58). If it's true, it will continue to the current code. Otherwise, the address of the method at `this + 8` is read and it jumps to this address.

You have different options to set a type to this memory part. Since it seems to be a pointer to something, go to this address address and type 'o' or `Edit → Operand type → Offset → Offset (data segment)`.